# Logging in silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

How can I log serverside domainservice ria errors in my domainservice in sl4?

I tried looking at clog, but that's not compiled for SL4, only SL3 and below

ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at NLog v2 http://nlog-project.org/  It's currently in beta, so use with caution. But my experience with it has been great.